# Как получить все возможные пути, найденный Волновым алгоритмом поиска вместо одного?

Tags: алгоритм, поиск-пути

Я реализовал поиск пути по Волновому алгоритму. Кратчайший путь успешно находился, однако, хоть он и был минимально длинным, он не являлся оптимальным при учете ряда других факторов. В процессе прочтения статьи на Википедии я наткнулся на такой отрывок текста:

> Трасс с минимальной числовой длиной пути [...] может существовать несколько. Выбор окончательного пути в приложениях диктуется другими соображениями, находящимися вне этого алгоритма.

Получение списка всех возможных путей вполне решило бы проблему, однако я ума не приложу какой алгоритм для этого стоит применить. Уже имеется рабочее поле со всеми расставленными числовыми отметками (как на рисунке), однако без найденного пути.

[image: Расставленные отметки]

Каким образом я могу получить все возможные варианты вместо одного?

Comment: Это какая то часть задачи? В чем суть самой задачи? Список всех возможных путей просто не влезет в память, особенно если допускаются циклы - то он вообще бесконечен и не ясно как приблизит к решению заачи.

Comment: во время работы волнового алгоритма (что по сути простой поиск в ширину), можно для каждой клетки отслеживать, откуда вы в эту клетку пришли и сколько это стоило, туда дойти. Так у вас получится что то типа [дейкстры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: Частью задачи это не является. Также хочу уточнить формулировку. Необходимо найти все возможные КРАТЧАЙШИЕ пути из точки А в точку Б, а их уже гораздо меньше. Алгоритм Дейкстры не подходит для данной задачи, поскольку ищет пути от одной точки во все.

Comment: раз дейскстра ищет кратчайшие во все, значит он найдет кратчайшие и в вашу точку в том числе, так чем он вам не подходит то тогда?

Comment: хотя тут надо определение "кратчайшего", если вам просто надо найти все пути минимальной длины (то есть путь с минимальным набором вершин), то поиск в ширину + хранение откуда вы в вершину пришли вам в помощь

Comment: в вот что значит `минимальной числовой длиной пути` это уже не понятно, если это не количество вершин, а что то другое, то тут уже дейкстра или беллман форд или что то из той же оперы

Comment: Вариантов может получится очень много. Из них всё равно придётся выбирать один вариант **при учете ряда других факторов**, верно? Тогда почему бы не модернизировать алгоритм так, чтобы он учитывал эти факторы при генерации пути?

Comment: Со временем эти факторы будут меняться, появляться новые и пропадать старые, поэтому переписывать алгоритм придется много. Намного проще получить все пути в списочек и уже отдельным модулем выбирать нужный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, что бы при использовании Волнового алгоритма получить все кратчайшие пути, а не только один, можно построить дерево, корнем которого будет клетка места назначения. Дочерними вершинами каждой вершины будут клетки вокруг нее, пометка на которых на один меньше чем пометка на корне. Таким образом, мы получим дерево, в котором количество листьев будет равняться количеству путей, и каждому листку будет соответствовать свой путь. Стоит учесть, что в таком дереве некоторые вершины будут иметь в себе одинаковые клетки.
Пример:

Для этого изображения дерево будет выглядеть так (Дерево не полное, однако каждый лист этого дерева в дальнейшем будет иметь идентичных детей):
[image: Метки]

[image: Дерево]